# How to use angular2 router-outlets when named outlet is not child of an outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have found excellent [example](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/)s how to use router-outlets with Angular 2 router. But, all of the examples deal with the case when your named outlet, e.g. , is inside your default router-outlet.

I have an application where I have to change a few things by a click and these areas are separated from each other. It would be hard to recreate the page to have them within each other.

Is there a solution for this? Is there an available example for cases like this?

Comment: i have the same situation, made two outlets one nameless and the other has name, yet only the nameless one get drawn...

Comment: I believe you'll get an error saying that there is no route with the name you given to your outlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a situation cannot be done. However, I had to rebuild my application again to avoid situations like I described.